# How to build apach Kylin cube on Hbase source data?

Tags: apache, hbase, apache-drill, kylin

I am new to **Kylin** and exploring same as well. It would be great if any one help me on below points :-

1. My source is **Hbase** , how can i connect to Kylin to Hbase and build
   cube?
2. Can Kylin connect Hbase through Drill ?
3. Can i sync FLATTENED
   table in Kylin ?

Thanks in advance , Any leads will be helpful.
Thanks,
Rahul S

Answer (score 2):

1.Kylin has a HBase dependency and the data is encoded. Kylin accepts only Hive,kafka and JDBC as input sources as of version 2.5. And writes data to Apache HBase. As a solution for this you can Map HBase data to Hive and then input data to kylin through Hive.

3. Yes you can sync flat tables to kylin through hive.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response , it worked for  me , i have one more question when i connecting Tableau 11 to Kylin cube and trying to see tables its showing me only Hive source table or may be Kylin Sync tables , its not showing me Kylin Cube or Hbase tables  which i build ? please tell me if i am missing anything. thanks Rahul

Comment: It should only show your source tables (Hive). HBase is there to store the cube.When you do querying with tableau it will query data from the prebuilt cube. Following guide will help. http://kylin.apache.org/docs/tutorial/tableau_91.html . if the question is answered please mark as answered.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it won't show the Kylin Cube or HBase table to you. You can use the table that Tableau shows to you to analyse. Then Kylin will search the Cube satisfied with query condition according to your query.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, i  have one more last question 
I have data in hbase and I am using Apache Drill to connect to this data. Can i connect to Drill from Apache Kylin ? any input will be helpful. thanks Rahul

Comment: As Nissanka Seneviratne saying,  Kylin accepts only Hive, Kafka and JDBC as input sources. So you can not connect to Drill from Kylin.

Comment: Nissanka Seneviratne and Handsome , thanks  for your response i moved forward due to your help. But getting error while building the Cube :-    Status: Failed
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1552447098248_0006_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1552447098248_0006_1_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tez.runtime.io.sort.mb 1892 should be larger than 0 and should be less than the available task memory (MB):157